# ER diagram for a bookstore

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have a `book store application` and i want to design it's database. Then first of all i need to it's E-R diagram.

`(This is not homework)`

It has so simple Scenario:

- Every User can have 0 , 1 , or more book order.
- There is more than one instance of each type of book.

Is this the best design?

[image]

Comment: Well, if you don't want people will vote for closing your question, try to re-formulate so it is more concrete. People generally do not like opinion-based questions like "is this the best solution?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a link between books and orderitems, not books and orders. The 'orders' table should be the central table. A simple structure would be

```
CUSTOMERS
id
name
adddress, etc

ORDERS
id
customer  (foreign key to customers table)
curdate
status  (open, closed)
% discount

ORDERITEMS
id
order    (foreign key to orders table)
book     (foreign key to books table)
quantity
price    
% discount
status (open, closed, ordered from distributor?)

BOOKS
id
title
author
costprice
salesprice
isbn
```

Comment: Nice, So how should be tables cardinalities?

Comment: For example, I know that cardinality between `users` and `Orders` is `1-n` . (If i didn't mistake)

Comment: Is the `Orders` and `OrderItems` cardinality can be `1-1` ?

Comment: One to many - each order has several orderitems, but each tuple of orderitems has one book only (but possible several copies). A book, of course, can appear in many orderitems.

Comment: @SajjadHTLO: I don't understand your comment. OrderItems needs a foreign key to its parent order (this is the 'order' field). 'id' is its own primary key. I suppose you could create a composite primary key from 'order' and 'book' but this would prevent being able to order the same book twice in an order (say, one time standard packaging and one time gift wrapping). So it's better to have a unique, automatic key for orderitems.